# Choosing between using count with filter and altering the on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, count

There are 2 tables, `video` and `category`.

```
create table category (
    id integer primary key,
    name text
);

create table video (
    id integer primary key,
    category_id integer references category (id),
    quality text
);

insert into category (id, name) values (1, 'Entertainment');
insert into category (id, name) values (2, 'Drawing');

insert into video (id, category_id, quality) values (1, 1, 'sd');
insert into video (id, category_id, quality) values (2, 1, 'hd');
insert into video (id, category_id, quality) values (3, 1, 'hd');
```

I can get the list of all categories with the number of all videos.

```
select category.id, category.name, count(video)
from category left outer join video
on (category.id = video.category_id)
group by category.id;
```

result

```
 id |     name      | count 
----+---------------+-------
  2 | Drawing       |     0
  1 | Entertainment |     3
(2 rows)
```

To get all categories with the number of HD videos, both of these queries can be used.

**count with filter**

```
select
category.id,
category.name,
count(video) filter (where video.quality='hd')
from category left outer join video
on (category.id = video.category_id)
group by category.id;
```

**result**

```
 id |     name      | count 
----+---------------+-------
  2 | Drawing       |     0
  1 | Entertainment |     2
(2 rows)
```

**on**

```
select
category.id,
category.name,
count(video)
from category left outer join video
on (category.id = video.category_id and video.quality='hd')
group by category.id;
```

**result**

```
 id |     name      | count 
----+---------------+-------
  2 | Drawing       |     0
  1 | Entertainment |     2
(2 rows)
```

The results are equal. What are the pros and cons of using the first and the second way? Which one is preferred?

Comment: I would probably even push the aggregation into the derived table in the second case. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8fcb6af84a47839410e87ff833c0fe0b

Answer (score 2):

The second query is somehow more efficient, because the `on` predicate of the `join` reduces the number of rows earlier, while the first query keeps them all, and then relies on the filter of the aggregate function. I would recommend the second query.

The first query would be useful if you were, for example, to perform several conditional counts, like:

```
select
    category.id,
    category.name,
    count(*) filter (where video.quality='hd') no_hd_videos,
    count(*) filter (where video.quality='sd') no_sd_videos
from category 
left outer join video on category.id = video.category_id
group by category.id;
```

Comment: I would just use `count(*)`.  `count(video)` is redundant because `NULL` values are handled by the `filter`.